# How to calibrate an external microphone device?

Tags: android, signal-processing, microphone, recording

I have been working on a research project which involves making audio recordings to perform some digital signal processing analysis.

To aid me in my recording, my research supervisor has provided me with an i436 microphone. It looks like [this](http://www.mic-w.com/product.php?id=3). However, before making the recording he has asked me to calibrate the device.

I have a rather blurry idea of what calibration means. Since different microphones may have different intensities / recording conditions, they will generate different results for the same recording. A calibration of the microphone device will generate a result in an acceptable range of 1 dB.

I searched through the internet and after digesting the seemingly indigestible concepts of using a hardware device to calibrate a microphone, I have come back here to ask for experts views on this.

If someone could explain in detail what calibrating a microphone means and how it can be achieved using a software on either an android device or a windows laptop, I would be grateful.

I don't want to purchase a new hardware device to calibrate a microphone but would rather appreciate software that do the same.

Currently I have the following equipment: An android device (Moto g3), Windows 10 laptop, iPhone 5S (not mine but I can borrow it).

Comment: You will need calibrated hardware to compare against or measure.  Perhaps borrow a calibrated unit.  The 5s microphone isn't guaranteed by Apple to be calibrated, but there are iOS apps that claim some degree of accuracy.  There may also be an iOS app for the i436 mic.  Try one of those, and adjust your's to match those measurements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will surely try one of the ways that you have suggested.